# Moq: different return values for first and later invocations

Tags: c#, properties, moq

Can I set up a property of an interface in Moq so that it returns `0` on first invocation and `10` for all further invocations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Mock<IFoo> foo = new Mock<IFoo>(MockBehavior.Strict);

bool isFirstCall = true;
foo.Setup(item => item.GetInt())
   .Returns(() =>
   {
       if (isFirstCall)
       {
           isFirstCall = false;
           return 0;
       }
       return 10;
   });
```